# How do I check $(\frac{e}{n})^n*n!$ for convergence?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

As stated in the title I am looking for a way to show that
$(\frac{e}{n})^n*n!$
diverges with n approaching infinity.
I recently ran into this problem and I cannot seem to find an answer for it. I assume that e is the edge case here since any number smaller than e leads to convergence (at least according to wolfram). I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: I would use Stirling's asymptotic formula, which shows that your sequence is equivalent to $\sqrt{2\pi n}$ at $+\infty$. This also shows that $e$ is indeed the "edge case". Any constant $ \geq 0$ strictly smaller than $e$ will yield convergence.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.